# Issue with inline VF page from Managed package on org where SSO is setup

Tags: managed-package, single-sign-on, redirect, inline-visualforce

I am facing weird problem on one of customers org. The inline VF page is not working on one specific org when we use SSO to login on that org. If we use normal login then it works fine.

When we login with SFDC user name password the url is something like: 
https://xxxxxxx--dev1.cs21.my.salesforce.com (lets call it A url)

When we login with service provider initiated SSO the url is like this:
https://yyyyyyyydev1crm.zzzzzdev.aaaaaa.net (lets call it B url)

Here are my findings till now:
When user login with B url his inline VF page does not load properly.

The inline VF page is added on cases standard page.

When we checked the network traffic it showed that request for inline VF page is is redirected to SSO end point for authorization. After authorization it redirect to home page. As result user see home page instead of inline VF page. 
So my guess is its loosing the retURL in this redirect. But I am not sure.

[image]

My Question is: how to fix this issue?

Comment: Some questions: 1) Are you using SP initiated SSO or IDP initiated SSO 2) Did you check the iframe source of the inline VF page

Comment: Thank you for your response. we are using SP initiated SSO. Yes i checked the source of i frame and its showing URL A. And as you cam see URL A and B are not same so its redirecting to SSO for authorization but not coming back to original URL and instead going to home page. and that home page is getting displayed in VF.

Comment: Check the session settings... Are the users' logins locked to an IP address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found two work around for this. Both are just workaround and not the perfect fit solutions.

1) We provided link to URL A on home page and trained users to click on it when they log in so user is authenticated on both the URL and then issue does not show up.

*The problem with solution one is its not automatic and user need to click on link to use our app which is very pathetic user experience.*

2) We added home page component (of VF page type) on left panel which content a VF page from package. So when user loges in home page component load URL A and user is authenticated on both the URL and then issue does not show up. for better UI we can make the height of component as 1 or 0 to hide it.

*The problem with solution 2) is, its automatic but user needs to wait till the component load completely. If user do not wait then it does not work properly.*

I have accepted this as an answer for now but if some one have better solution to this then please share it.